# upgrade to postgresSql 12.2 getting continuous logs LOG: Failed to reopen the file pg_stat/global.stat retrying

Tags: postgresql

Getting below message in postgres logs, after upgrading my db from 9.0.4 to 12.2

LOG: Failed to reopen the file pg_stat/global.stat retrying.

I have checked the pg_stat directory and im not seeing any file named global.stat.

Any help ?

Comment: Too little information.

Comment: 1) Postgres 12.7 is the most recent minor version of 12. 2) OS and version? 3) How did you do the upgrade? 4) How did you start the new version?